# Magento 2.2.6 Exception message: A wrong PayPal Express Checkout Token is specified

Tags: payment-methods, payment, magento2.2.6, paypal-express

I am getting this issue for a few customers in the production site. while trying place order in one step checkout with **PayPal express checkout**, it's redirecting to the cart page with the exception

> A wrong PayPal Express Checkout Token is specified.

I am not getting this issue for all customers, also I am unable to replicate this issue.

Also, I found in `logreport.CRITICAL`:

```
Exception message: A wrong PayPal Express Checkout Token is specified. Trace: #0 /app/yvwkeqc4fanxa/vendor/magento/module-paypal/Controller/Express/AbstractExpress/ReturnAction.php(32): Magento\Paypal\Controller\Express\AbstractExpress->_initToken() #1 /app/yvwkeqc4fanxa/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): Magento\Paypal\Controller\Express\AbstractExpress\ReturnAction->execute()
```

Has anyone have the solution for this issue.

Comment: also, i found in logreport.CRITICAL: Exception message: A wrong PayPal Express Checkout Token is specified.
Trace: #0 /app/yvwkeqc4fanxa/vendor/magento/module-paypal/Controller/Express/AbstractExpress/ReturnAction.php(32): Magento\Paypal\Controller\Express\AbstractExpress->_initToken()
#1 /app/yvwkeqc4fanxa/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): Magento\Paypal\Controller\Express\AbstractExpress\ReturnAction->execute()

Answer (score 0):

This can be temporarily rectified by disabling any Paypal payment methods in the back end, Flushing all cache. then re-enabling the payment methods, and re flushing all cache.

It appears this sometimes happens after a rebuild of the static files or a move to "production mode"  which is also rebuilding static files.